# Flutter clean architecture with Bloc, RxDart and StreamBuilder, Stateless vs Stateful and dispose

Tags: flutter, dispose, bloc, rxdart, statelesswidget

I'm trying to implement a clean architecture with no dependency of the framework in the business' logic layers.

The following example is a Screen with only a `Text`. I make an API Rest call in the repository and add the response to a `BehaviorSubject` that is listened through a `StreamBuilder` that will update the `Text`. Since is an `StatefulWidget` I'm using the `dispose` method to close the `BehaviorSubject`'s `StreamController`.

The example is simplified, no error/loading state handling, no dependency injection, base classes, dispose interfaces etc.

```dart
class Bloc {
  final UserReposiotry _userReposiotry;
  final BehaviorSubject<int> _activeUsersCount = BehaviorSubject.seeded(0);

  Bloc(this._userReposiotry) {
    _getActiveUsersCount();
  }

  void _getActiveUsersCount() async {
    final response = await _userReposiotry.getActiveUsersCount();
    _activeUsersCount.add(response.data);
  }

  ValueStream<int> get activeUsersCount => _activeUsersCount.stream;

  void dispose() async {
    await _activeUsersCount.drain(0);
    _activeUsersCount.close();
  }
}

class StatefulScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Bloc bloc;

  const StatefulScreen({Key? key, required this.bloc}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulScreen> createState() => _StatefulScreenState();
}

class _StatefulScreenState extends State<StatefulScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stream = widget.bloc.activeUsersCount;
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: stream,
      initialData: stream.value,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I have the following doubts regarding this approach.

1. `StreamBuilder` cancels the `stream` subscription automatically, but it doesn't close the `StreamController`. I know that you should close it if you are reading a file, but in this case, if I don't manually close it, once the `StatefulScreen` is no longer in the navigation stack, could it be destroyed, or it would be a *memory leak*?
2. I've seen a lot of people using `StatelessWidget` instead of `StatefulWidget` using `Stream` and `StreamBuilder` approach, if it is really needed to close the `BehaviorSubject` it is a problem since we don't have the `dispose` method, I found about the `WillPopScope` but it won't fire in all navigation cases and also and more important would it be more performant an approach like `WillPopScope`, or having an `StatefulWidget` *wrapper* (`BlocProvider`) inside an `StatelessWidget` just to do the dispose, than using an `StatefulWidget` directly, and if so could you point to an example of that implementation?
3. I'm currently choosing `StatefulWidget` for widgets that have animations o controllers (map, text input, pageview...) or streams that I need to close, the rest `StatelessWidget`, is this correct or am I missing something?
4. About the `drain` method, I'm using it because I've encountered an error navigating back while an API rest call was on progress, I found a member of the **RxDart** team saying it isn't really necessary to call `drain` so I'm confused about this too..., the error:

> You cannot close the subject while items are being added from addStream

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you find an answer?
im interested

Comment: @KamiTzayig I moved from that, too much boilerplate, I'm now using **Riverpod** and its code gen lib plus **Freezed** for the **State** models, way less boilerplate, every class can be reactive without extra work, and non UI or Flutter stuff in the business logic (Repository, Service etc).